# Python code to count business days in ArcGIS field calculator gives ERROR 999999?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, error-999999

I'm trying to field calculate using a python script the number of business days between two given dates.  Right now the dates are hard coded, but once I get the script working I will pass dates from two other fields to it.  The script works fine in IDLE, giving me the correct number of business days, but when I put it in the field calculator it errors out:

> ERROR 999999: Error executing function
>
> The field is not nullable.

The field is set as "Short" with Precision at 5.

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

def workdays():
    start = dt.date(2018, 1, 31)
    end = dt.date(2018, 2, 12)
    days = np.busday_count(start, end)
    return days
```

Field=

```
workdays()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is returning data type numpy.int64 which is probably not compatible with field type Short. Try `return int(days)`